# Using DateColumnGenerator

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm working on a task where I have to show the content to a folder inside a vaadin table:

[image]

Now I would want to remove the hours, minutes and second from **last update** column, but I'm not able to do this. Try to describe my situation a little bit better:

I'm making the table in this way:

```
private Table makeTableFiles(){

    Table tableToReturn = new Table();
    tableToReturn.addContainerProperty("iconProperty", Image.class, null);
    tableToReturn.addContainerProperty("fileNameProperty", String.class,null);
    tableToReturn.addContainerProperty("lastUpdateProperty", Date.class, null);

    //tableToReturn.addGeneratedColumn("lastUpdateProperty", new DateColumnGenerator());
    Object [] visibleColumns = new Object [] {"iconProperty","fileNameProperty","lastUpdateProperty"};
    String [] columnHeaders = new String [] {"",getI18NMessage("fileNameHeader"),getI18NMessage("lastUpdateHeader")};
    tableToReturn.setVisibleColumns(visibleColumns);
    tableToReturn.setColumnHeaders(columnHeaders);
    tableToReturn.setSelectable(true);
    tableToReturn.setSizeFull();
    return tableToReturn;

}
```

And I'm filling my table in this way:

```
private void populateTable(String dirToShow){

    File dir  = new File (dirToShow);
    for(File file : dir.listFiles()){

        Date lastUpdate = new Date(file.lastModified());
        String fileName = file.getName();

        Object [] objToAdd = null;

        if(file.isDirectory())
            objToAdd = new Object [] { new Image("", new ThemeResource("../runo/icons/16/folder.png")),fileName,lastUpdate};

        else{
            objToAdd = new Object [] { new Image("", new ThemeResource("../runo/icons/16/document.png")),fileName,lastUpdate};
        }

        tableFilesToProcess.addItem(objToAdd,fileName);
    }
    }
```

Usually I solve this proble adding a **DateColumnGenerator** at the property, but now doesn't work.

If I add the following line of code:

```
tableToReturn.addGeneratedColumn("lastUpdateProperty", new DateColumnGenerator());
```

no item is added.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you use `table.addItem(cells, itemId)` with generated columns. The method javadoc writes:

> Adds the new row to table and fill the visible cells (except generated columns) with given values.

You should try something like this:

```
tableToReturn.addGeneratedColumn("genCol", new DateColumnGenerator() {
    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        super.generateCell(source, itemId, "lastUpdateProperty");
    }
});
Object [] visibleColumns =
        new Object [] {"iconProperty","fileNameProperty","genCol"};
```

And one more important thing: add items first then add generated column.

Comment: Interesting approach to call generateCell on the other column. But in general I don't like the generatedColumn approach here, because you create a new column and hide the original one, just for the sake of formatting (as you also loose the sorting functionality). Perfect solution would be to add a ColumnGenerator (or formatter) to a given column.

Comment: Overall I agree with you. Probably a better solution, if `formatPropertyValue()` is used for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to not use the addGeneratedColumn but override formatPropertyValue in your table:

```
@Override
protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId, Property<?> property) {
    if (property.getType() == Date.class) {
        return getFormattedDate((Date) property.getValue());
    }
    return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
}
```